# Route with intent and condition requirement seems does not work on dialogflow CX

Tags: google-cloud-platform, chatbot, dialogflow-cx

I create  a simple test to explain the problem.
route with condition and intent requirements seems not workable on dialgoflow

I have 3 pages:

1. start-page
2. Location-page
3. End-page

I want to prompt the user to enter a location e.g. city, state, (city-state), ...

In the Location-page, I define a parameter called "Local" with entity type `@city-state-country-workaround-entity.` that I defined

In the same page, I define a route based on a custom intent `GetLocation` to extract the location that match the custom entity defined above. In the condition field, I set a rule: `$page.params.local.status = "UPDATED"` and in the transition I set `End-page`.

I expect that this solution works but it does not!

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXBPq.png)

[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8aeq.png)

However, when I remove the condition from the first route and create an additional route with the same condition, it works fine!!

[Image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSw3u.png)

Does it make sense! In the documentation:
*Routes have two requirements, and **one or both must be provided**. If both requirements are provided, they both must be satisfied in order to call the route*